# adding line break into javascript from php

Tags: javascript, php, str-replace, line-breaks

Please bear with me as this is not easy to explain. I have a field in a MySQL database that was put there from a form with a textarea input. It seems to me that line breaks are coded as "/n"

When I retrieve the data I can display it on the screen correctly by using the following php lines

```
$main_article1 = str_replace("\n", "<br />", $row[main_article]);
echo $mainarticle1;
```

However, now comes the tricky bit. I then want to insert that text into a scroller that uses Javascript.

The code in that script is:

```
var pausecontent=new Array()

pausecontent[0]='<?php echo $main_article1;?>'
```

I just get a blank screen.

If I remove the line breaks from the text in the database all works well - the main_article text appears  in the scroller as it should - it only stops working when the line breaks are there.

Does anyone know how I can get the line breaks in the database field to go through the PHP script and appear in the scroller text in the Javascript?

I have also tried:

```
$main_article1 = str_replace("/n>", "%0D%0A", $row[main_article]);
```

but that does not work either

I hope I have made sense of what I am trying to do.

Many thanks in advance.

Tog

Here is an update

```
$main_article = 'This is a test<br />This is a test'
```

the code generated by php within the JS should be:

```
pausecontent[0]='This is a test<br />This is a test'
```

(all greyed out) but what I am getting is:

```
pausecontent[0]='This is a test
This is a test'
```

and the line break in the JS code is causing it to fail because the text is no longer greyed out after the line break

Comment: Anything in the error logs? Any reason not to use the `nl2br` function? Is the whole page blank or just the JS not executing, if just JS anything in the console?

Comment: Step one: Check the generated JS code – does that look as it should?

Comment: I get the same result using the nl2br function. The page loads OK but the JS does not run. If I input text that does not have a line break the JS runs fine

Comment: OK the JS code is wrong. It has line breaks in it and instead it should just have<br /> tags. If I replace the line breaks manually with <br /> tags it works - but doing it with php doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it at last, after too many days headache!

I was looking at the wrong replacement theories

The answer is to use the following line:

```
$main_article1 = preg_replace("/\r\n|\r|\n/",'<br/>',$row[main_article]);
```

Now it works perfectly.

Thanks to all for your help.

Regards

Tog

Comment: Just use the `nl2br`, no need to reinvent a function. `Returns string with '<br />' or '<br>' inserted before all newlines (\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r).` http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: @chris85 That did not work because it inserted the '<br>' tag in front of the other ones but I needed to completely remove any '/r/n' instances, which is why the preg_replace function did work where the nl2br function did not work. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the nl2br() function

```
$main_article1 = nl2br($row[main_article]);
```

also I suggest leaving a space between your code and the closing php tag (`?>`)

```
pausecontent[0]='<?php echo $main_article1; ?>'
```

Comment: Tried both of those but the problem still remains